# How to prevent loading of Richfaces 4 component css files

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I'm upgrading from Richfaces 3.3 to 4.

I have a number of custom css files and skins.

Richfaces 4 seems to have added a whole load of new classes to various components i.e. rf-tab, rf-tab-cnt, etc.
These components have styles associated with them (They appear to be loaded in ecss file with names like panel.ecss, datascroller.ecss, etc)

They have really messed up my current UI layout :(

Is there any way to disable the loading of all these component stylessheets?

I tried applying the following but it does not work:

```
<context-param>
  <param-name>org.richfaces.LoadStyleStrategy</param-name>
  <param-value>NONE</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
  <param-name>org.ajax4jsf.COMPRESS_STYLE</param-name>
  <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use 'plain' skin. This way most CSS classes will be rendered but not defined...

Comment: That causes a problem, I need to specify a dynamic skin of my own here i.e. <param-value>#{productInfo.skin}</param-value>. putting 'plain' in there results in my custom skin not getting loaded.

Comment: Just have getSkin() return your custom skin.

Comment: I'm not following Max. Where is getSkin() defined? Is it part of some custom bean you create?

Comment: It's defined as a bean getter, which returns the current skin.